# Стиль кнопки в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка. На ней сверху лежит StackPanel с картинкой и надписью. Нужно изменить фон этой панели в зависимости от значений свойств IsEnabled и IsMouseOver. Стандартный триггер стиля кнопки позволяет менять только фон кнопки, а надо по срабатыванию триггера менять фон StackPanel. 
Как из триггера в стиле добраться до StackPanel и изменить ее свойства?

Вот код:

```
<Button x:Name="resetSelect" Grid.Column="4" Content="Снять все" Foreground="White" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="7,0,0,5" 
                        Background="#6c7a89"
                        FontSize="12" Height="75" Click="resetSelect_Click">
                    <Button.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="67" Width="55">
                                <Image Source="/ImagesNew/ClearSelect.png" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="45"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Button.ContentTemplate>
                </Button>
```

Comment: дополните ваш вопрос XAML-кодом

Comment: Вы как вставляете StackPanel? Через XAML? Тогда вы можете добавить DataTrigger в свою панель с байндингом на свойство IsPressed в кнопке.

Answer (score 3):

Вот вам простой пример, но, тут используется `VisualStateManager`, для смены, цвета, и всего необходимого.

```
<Style x:Key="BtnFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle
                    Margin="2"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                    Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                    StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                    StrokeThickness="1" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="DefaultBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{DynamicResource BtnFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,11,12,10" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint" Value="Enabled" />
    <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="Fant" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Helvetica Arial sans-serif" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Static.Background.Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Static.Foreground.Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource Static.Border.Brush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness=".9"
                    CornerRadius="2">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="PART_Button"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="Common">
                            <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="{DynamicResource MouseOver.Background.Color}" />
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="{DynamicResource MouseOver.Border.Color}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="{DynamicResource Pressed.Background.Color}" />
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                        To="{DynamicResource Pressed.Border.Color}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="Normal" />
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="MouseOver">
                                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="10" />
                                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="Pressed">
                                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="10" />
                                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="Focused">
                                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Exponent="10" />
                                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".6" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="CustomDarkButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#6c7a89" Name="Panel">
                    <Image Source="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Img}" Margin="0,8,0,0" Width="55" MaxHeight="45" />
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#ADD8E6"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="#6c7a89"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background"  Value="LightGray"/> 
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6,0,6,5"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
</Style>

<Button x:Name="SelectAll" Grid.Column="3" Content="Выделить все"  Height="75" Click="SelectAll_Click" Margin="7,0,0,5"
        Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CustomDarkButton}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <ImageSource x:Key="Img">/ImagesNew/SelectAll.png</ImageSource>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```